# Flagging duplicate answer (You-Know-Which)

Tags: discussion

I've flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48213322/10550549) from the question [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript). This answer was posted in **11/01/2018** (dd/MM/yyyy) and mentioned about using `forEach` method.

As we can *see*, the content of that answer **(without any explanation)** was already posted before.

Some of those *(in the same question)* are:

1. [The accepted answer with 7213 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/10550549) - posted in 17/02/2012
2. [The answer with 532 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329496/10550549) - posted in 17/02/2012
3. [The answer with 36 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24336808/10550549) - posted in 20/06/2014
4. [The answer with 20 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43309349/10550549) - posted in 09/04/2017
5. [The answer with 8 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205719/10550549) - posted in 09/11/2017
6. [The answer with 6 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47234998/10550549) - posted in 11/11/2017
7. [The answer with 10 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52728745/10550549) - posted in **09/10/2018** *(later but having good explanation)*
8. [The answer with 7 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51381464/10550549) - posted in **17/07/2018** *(later but having good explanation)*

and 6 other good *(maybe)* answers.

---

And this is what I receive after flagging:

> [image]

So........ should I list all of them in the description box while flagging to describe what, where, and how?

---

Another scene, how could that answer be unique? Not only a duplicate content, but it also has very low quality because of code-only. *(Not understand why it's still alive after reviewing by moderator)*

Comment: question says "Viewed 4.3m times" meaning it's one of [top 30 viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A4000000) all times - it clearly deserves bringing attention to at meta, getting protected and [Atwood cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: @gnat The accepted answer from the link you gave me, it requires to flag with content: `This answer is a duplicate of an answer already posted two years ago`. My post explains what's happen after doing that. Not duplicate.

Comment: message of your flag looks too vague to qualify as a useful description of the problem for the moderator ("Duplicate answer") meaning the way proposed int he other question would probably work better (I personally prefer even more detailed flag messages than proposed there). Though in this particular case bringing the question to meta looks like even better way, because of enormous 4 million views on the question

Comment: @gnat Nope. Think different. The answer I flagged becomes duplicate from almost the others in that question. What does it mean? It means some moderator didn't check the other answers. Just requires *what, where and how*

Comment: thinking differently won't help here sorry. Moderators handle hundreds flags a day and it is not reasonable to expect them study multiple answers trying to guess which one you meant as duplicate in some random question (if I flagged, I would at the very least mention 4 millions views ion this question - quite a pity that you didn't)

Comment: @gnat *Hundreds flags a day* is not the reason. If he/she dosen't have time, just skip it. Other moderator will do. I won't say that he/she didn't review the answer I flagged. Because there is another reason to delete: code-only answer. It already has a comment with 5 upvotes inside.

Comment: you better have a look at past meta discussions in [meta-tag:declined-flags] tag. Duplicate answers typically don't qualify (unfortunately) for mod attention, except when there is a provable plagiarism. Same to code-only answers (again, unfortunately). To avoid misunderstanding, I believe that answer you flagged is worth mod attention, as well as all other answers you listed here - it is just the way you flagged it (message "duplicate answer" and nothing else) was essentially doomed to fail

Comment: I don't think mods should spend time looking for an appropriate dupe for you - it is simply not their "job" (yes, even if the answers are all on the same page). I flag dupe answers from time to time - a message includes the username and timestamp (or something like "yesterday") of the source answer, as well as some info on *why* the post is a dupe. Yet to see any being declined. So I think the reason is to avoid feedback loop - you flag with just "duplicate", a mod approves it, you repeat it the next time. If from now on you will use more descriptive messages - then this is a win for everyone.

Comment: @gnat Catching mod attention? Don't let mod misunderstand? Really??? `STOP! Look and Listen` like the way we are? Why we vote for him to become a moderator and now we must explain he may *misunderstand*? If this was a test, he didn't pass. Because it's really duplicate. I have no more thing to say. Best regard!

Comment: Why are you being so hostile towards the moderators. You could have provided a single example in your flag and it would have helped.

Comment: @SecurityHound in fact, I'm not sure why OP is so hostile to the suggestion of providing objectively better more accurate data which costs basically *nothing* (they already know what the dupe is, takes seconds to point it out) and helps everybody involved.

Comment: As a moderator on another SE site, I can only say that the flag page only shows: the post being flagged and the flag reason (and optionally the question, but needs another click to show it), all inside a relatively small window; there are no other posts shown on there. Making a mod work harder by determining themselves which is the duplicate is an extra effort and even unclear at best. As for why it's still alive, well, mods don't judge wrong/bad answers; they should be downvoted (in fact, **no one has downvoted that answer**), and only negative score posts can be deleted by the community.

Comment: this is not about catching attention. Handling flags is main duty of moderators and system already does a pretty good job ensuring that they do that. I cast several tens thousands flags and none was missed. As I wrote, flag message should help moderators understand why their action is needed - and "duplicate answer" doesn't do that

Comment: I typically just go in the moderator chat for my primary community, write a small message, with a link to the trouble contribution.  Flags are primarily only helpful in the most obvious cases.  Being able to provide formatted information in a flag would indeed be helpful.

Comment: @SecurityHound moderator chat?

Comment: @OlegValter - On my primary community there is a chatroom where the community moderators hangout.  I am sure SO has one

Comment: @SecurityHound - I see, thanks. Don't think there is a single one (unless you refer to the Blue Room, but afaik it is not accessible to normal users), SOCVR might be one with [del-pls], but I've seen only one such req there as flagging is the usual way to go. That said, I agree that dropping a note in the respective language community if one is not sure does not hurt

Comment: @SecurityHound There is the network wide "teachers' lounge", but because it's network wide I think it's more for general moderating issues and discussion, it would probably be less useful on site specific issues. There is no other "moderator chat" (and it's obviously moderator only... Kind of a requirement for a moderator chat)

Comment: @Nick - It's a "Ask .. Moderator" chat.  I am not going to reveal my primary community.  It's hidden for a good reason.